# When should I do certain SQLite operations on another thread(not the main thread)?

Tags: android, sqlite

My Android application includes an SQLite database with an `SQLiteOpenHelper` class to help manage it.  During application use, the user may perform some operations such as adding/deleting/updating etc on the database.

At some points the size of the operation will be known, like this:

1. user clicks button to save item
2. the `SQLiteDatabase` performs a single `insert` query
3. user continues using app

At other areas of the app, the operation may be large, like inserting 10+ items into the database all at once.

Questions:

- should I thread simple operations like inserting/updating/deleting/viewing 1 item?
- will it take longer to insert 1 item into a table which contains many items(like 30+) than it would take to insert into a table with no items?
- if i don't need to thread such simple operations, at what point do you suggest i **start** threading them?

when i say **thread** i mean using a thread that is not the main UI thread.

edit: I realize that small operations do not take much time and i could very well get away with doing them on the main thread. I am just concerned that it would be bad practice to be executing them on the main thread and would like clarification!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

General rule for everything: If it's fast enough, do it on the main thread. If not, use a worker thread.

Unless you have a ridiculously huge database, a single operation almost never warrants a separate thread. Databases in general are designed to scale well, but of course a very big database (10,000+ rows?) will be a bit slower than a small one. 30 rows, however, is nothing.

I would start threading stuff if you have a lot of operations going on, like a bunch of queries, or complicated queries that span several tables.

As with everything - profile your app, and if it's too slow, optimize. Don't write an awesome synchronized super-duper multi-core-ready database handler if none of your queries takes longer than 2ms.

Comment: What about the talk on Android REST client applications at google IO. He says "never execute database operations in the context of the main thread". I hope I am not taking that out of the context, but it may be a good practice.

Comment: I still stand by the last sentence - don't optimize what's not slow. If your database is very small, there shouldn't be a need to optimize it. Adding multi-threading will increase the complexity of your app a lot and introduce a fascinating breeding ground for synchronization bugs that are impossibly hard to spot and debug.

Comment: Use Loaders, they are now available as part of the compatibility library.

Comment: Depending on what SQLite library you use it might not be a big problem to move things to a background thread. I'm using anko currently and it does not care what thread database operations run on. It handles concurrency problems for you. I have several database operations on the Main thread and a Foreground Service that accesses the database with a kotlin coroutine using the IO thread. Didn't have any problem with that and didn't have to implement any thread safety myself. So, you don't have to optimize if not needed. But it's arbitrary to do so if you need it using libraries like anko.

Answer (score 6):

Always measure before you optimize!

Make sure that DB operations you do affect user experience and than start looking for a solution.

If database stuff gets slow, then use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), which was designed to perform tasks in the background, and then update the GUI on EDT.

Comment: Even usage of Loader could be done instead of AsyncTask. It has many advantages to address the loading of data off the UI thread.

[link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html)

Comment: What does EDT stand for?

Answer (score 2):

There is absoulutely not reason to use a thread here. Just return the cursor, extract the information from the cursor and return it to the main activity.

Specifically speaking a thread is something ideally that is going to repeat until something happens or it times out. Since the database you are using i'm assuming is on the phone, it would take practically zero time to access it.

Also another thing you can do is create a Utility class to assist with your activity to database interaction. It would be what your activity calls to interact with the database. Specifically the flow of control would be like this:

Activity -> Utility -> Database

Its between the activity and the database to keep them isolated from each other and make it much easier to access whatever it needs since it doesn't have to go directly to the database itself.

Comment: A thread is useful for doing something in parallel to another thread. It is a good idea to use a separate thread when you are not guaranteed that it will come back quickly which is the case with anything that accesses the disk since another thread/process/app could cause disk contention. SQLite access is disk heavy.