# Android - should all database operations be done in a thread?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I do certain SQLite operations on another thread(not the main thread)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047378/when-should-i-do-certain-sqlite-operations-on-another-threadnot-the-main-thread)

I am wondering, should all SQLite database operations in my android app be done in a thread, or can small ones, such as adding a single row, be used on the UI thread?

Comment: please provide more description about the task that you are trying to implement exactly

Comment: I am just adding a single row to a SQLite database.

Comment: good question! but I think we don't have a good answer yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its purely a matter of choice .

While some stubbornly say that all DB operation must be in thread while others might not feel the same.

So it depends on the developer and how he wants the UI to be.

In my opinion creating thread for a simple write operation is actually an overhead and would be more convenient to be on UI thread.

But beware of such usage an exception can cause your UI thread to be exceptioned.

Answer (score 0):

probably small access can be done but I would still use a thread -- write some code and test

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary to do all DB operation in thread but its recommend to do that.And while you are using thread then always remember do not update UI from inside.Use handler class to update UI

Answer (score -2):

In all but the most complex operations, getting a couple of indices in place should make all local DB operations blazingly fast.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - which is about which thread a DB operation should be performed on, not how to improve database performance.