# Does every sql query need to be executed in another thread, and if not, how approximately be normal to be handled on main thread?

Tags: java, android, sql, multithreading, sqlite

I have app, that saves note, and in that query i just saves note with title and body in database, and it seems for me that i doesn't have to put it in another thread. But on other side when i reads all notes, (that part i didn't do yet), do i need to put it to another thread, i don't have animation or similar to cause some lagging or similar?

MyMain question would be do i need for everysingle sql query no matter how long and complexity, to put in another thread, because that may be casual way to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047378/when-should-i-do-certain-sqlite-operations-on-another-threadnot-the-main-thread

Comment: Thanks, i didn't succeed to find this post, or maybe i didn't tried enough...

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is no need for another thread, but it depends on your situation (off the top of my head, I can't come up with a scenario where another thread is needed).

Comment: So why this topic, not closed : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047378/when-should-i-do-certain-sqlite-operations-on-another-threadnot-the-main-thread

Comment: I guess it depends on how long your query is taking and how long you think is reasonable for the user to wait for a response. Inserting a record shouldn't take too long, but querying for notes might take longer. Use your judgment.